# Delphi FMX RTL270.bpl error with visual component TbackendEndpoint

Tags: delphi

I don't know if it is a Bug or my configuration is wrong. Can anyone verify that Failure?

1. Create FireMonkey APP
2. Create DataModul with TBackenAuth and TEMSProvider
3. Create Form with TBackenendpoint on it. Declare Provider and Auth object from DataModul
4. Save Projekt and Close it
5. Reopen Project and open Designtime Panel on Form

Edit:
Bug is Reported under: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-33909

Edit 2 / Workaround:
The Problem can be "solved" by keeping the DataModule open. If you open the Datamodule first and after that the unit with the Components on it, it works.

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: It says Access Violation on Adress xy

Comment: Error like that in IDE is a bug, either in Emba code or code of some installed packages.

Comment: I can reproduce the error! It looks like a bug. You could fill a report at https://quality.embarcadero.com. Publish the number here.

Comment: Bug is reported here: https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-33909

Answer (score 3):

**Updated on 10-May-21:** After some reloading of the project I also see the described AV and I can therefore confirm this RSP too. Initially, the form with the BackendEndpoint1 component could be opened, but after some opening and closing of the project, I saw the Access Violation too. Once it helped to delete the *identcache* file of the project manually. Unfortunately, this workaround did not work reliably either. You'll probably have to wait for a solution from Embarcadero.

[image]

The above image shows the situation before the AV in the Delphi IDE began.

Comment: I am up to date. Updated yesterday. Was thinking that the Problem maybe would be solved. Can you Provid your Code for the Component? I Mean the textual notation for that visible Components? The Problem woul appear before showing the Visual Components. After the Failure there is no Design Tab available

Comment: @schneider infosystems You said: "When I reopen the form". It is the whole project you have to save and reopen, not only the form. Use menu / File / Close All and then Menu / File / Open project and select the project (Or open it from the welcome page).

Comment: @fpiette: Of course, I have reopened the project in the IDE. See the bold marked update in my text.

Comment: @fisi-pjm:  For legal reasons, the reproduction of Embarcadero's component code is not allowed. However, I would be happy to help you and can offer you a short screen-sharing session, where we briefly look for the differences on my PC. The best way to do this is via the Delphi Slack group: https://delphiprogrammers.slack.com I can be found there under my company name with a direct message.

Comment: @SchneiderInfosystemsLtd what do you mean with "reproduction of Embarcadero's component code is not allowed". I Thin we talk past each other. I MEan something like:
object Panel1: TPanel
    Left = 0
    Top = 46
    Width = 852
    Height = 365
    Align = alClient
    Caption = 'Panel1'
    TabOrder = 0
end
The code you get when you hit alt+F12

Comment: Ah, then I misunderstood you. I will post this information to the result. And this morning, I see the AV in rtl270.bpl the first time too! I will change my answer completely! But before I do some additional tests!